# Mockito `when` on real object

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito

I want to mock Dao class when object contains specific values. For example, I want to mock call to the database when `userlist.getStatus == UserlistStatus.DONE`

If attached the code snippet.

my application code is as follow:

```
UserlistBo userlistBo = userlistDao.getByIdAndPublisherId(userlistId, publisher.getId());
if (userlistBo.getStatus() == UserlistStatus.SOURCE_IN_PROGRESS && userlistStatusDto.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase(UserlistStatus.DONE.getValue())) {
    userlistBo.setStatus(UserlistStatus.DONE); // 1
    userlistBo = userlistDao.save(userlistBo); // 3
}
```

userlistBo object at marker 1 is as follow :

```
result = {UserlistBo@1610} "UserlistBo{id=1, name='ul-test-99-9999', status=DONE, source=SEGMENT, ruleId=1, publisherId=1, filename=filename.csv, createdById=null, lastModifiedById=null, creationTimestamp=null, lastModifiedTimestamp=null}"
```

and my test code looks like :

```
expectedUserlistBo.setId(1);
expectedUserlistBo.setName("ul-test-99-9999");
expectedUserlistBo.setPublisherId(1);
expectedUserlistBo.setRuleId(1);
expectedUserlistBo.setFilename("filename.csv");
expectedUserlistBo.setSource(UserlistSource.SEGMENT);
expectedUserlistBo.setStatus(UserlistStatus.SOURCE_IN_PROGRESS);
when(userlistDao.getByIdAndPublisherId(1, publisherBo.getId())).thenReturn(expectedUserlistBo);


UserlistBo expectedUserlistStatusDoneBo = new UserlistBo();
CopyHelperBean.copy(expectedUserlistStatusDoneBo, expectedUserlistBo);
expectedUserlistStatusDoneBo.setStatus(UserlistStatus.DONE); // 2
when(userlistDao.save(expectedUserlistStatusDoneBo)).thenReturn(expectedUserlistStatusDoneBo); // 4
```

userlistBo at marker 2 is :

```
result = {UserlistBo@1514} "UserlistBo{id=1, name='ul-test-99-9999', status=DONE, source=SEGMENT, ruleId=1, publisherId=1, filename=filename.csv, createdById=null, lastModifiedById=null, creationTimestamp=null, lastModifiedTimestamp=null}"
```

Since these two are different objects with the same values, when test is executed at marker 3, userlistBo is returned as `null` .

How should I mock at marker 4, so when Dao is called at marker 3, it will return me `expectedUserlistStatusDoneBo` instead of `null`?

Comment: 1. "different objects" ...yea respectively `==`,  but you can write (custom) `equals()+hashCode()` ..and use them! (also in test assertions) 2. (i am sure,) you can also do it with mockito, plz take a look at (when.)"thencallrealmethod" maybe also at  "mockito spy" (reset/verify..).

Comment: Thanks, Adding hashCode and equals for UserlistBo, solved the issue.

Comment: @xerx593 is it okay if I publish the answer? Since you helped me to resolve the question, I feel responsible for asking you.

Comment: sure, welcome, bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object in application code is

```
result = {UserlistBo@1610} "UserlistBo{id=1, name='ul-test-99-9999', status=DONE, source=SEGMENT, ruleId=1, publisherId=1, filename=filename.csv, createdById=null, lastModifiedById=null, creationTimestamp=null, lastModifiedTimestamp=null}"
```

Dummy object created in test code is

```
result = {UserlistBo@1514} "UserlistBo{id=1, name='ul-test-99-9999', status=DONE, source=SEGMENT, ruleId=1, publisherId=1, filename=filename.csv, createdById=null, lastModifiedById=null, creationTimestamp=null, lastModifiedTimestamp=null}"
```

though the values are same, these two are different objects

```
when(userlistDao.getByIdAndPublisherId(1, publisherBo.getId())).thenReturn(expectedUserlistBo);
```

in `when` condition, equality of above to object fails.
To Solve this, Added equals() and hashcode() in UserlistBo object.

@xerx593 thanks for pointing out